# set wrap_content for ListView horizontal use lib two way view

Tags: android

I user Two way view in [enter link description here][1]

[1]: https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view to create horizontal Listview in my app, I want create three list horizontal in a screen but when I add one List horizontal, height of it full screen, I can't set wrap_content or set value for height list view. How I do to add three list in a screen? thank you

Comment: can you edit your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create 1 Linear Layout for each ListView.
But dont set wrap_content for height of ListView. It will appear some error when using.